# NPE SpringLookupInitializer createLookup Spring-Vaadin 19+

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In trying to update to the latest version of Vaadin (20 at time of question), my application will not start due to NPE in the SpringLookupInitializer. When I was using Vaadin 19, which is where SpringLookupInitializer first started being used and I first started encountering the error I had to always use Spring-Vaadin 12.4.0 for the application to start up.  The error seems to be coming from this change...

In 12.4.0 there is code in SpringLookupInitializer defined as:

```
    @Override
    protected Lookup createLookup(VaadinContext context,
            Map<Class<?>, Collection<Class<?>>> services) {
        WebApplicationContext appContext = getApplicationContext(context);
        return new SpringLookup(appContext,
                (spi, impl) -> instantiate(appContext, spi, impl), services);
    }

    private WebApplicationContext getApplicationContext(VaadinContext context) {
        VaadinServletContext servletContext = (VaadinServletContext) context;
        WebApplicationContext appContext = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getWebApplicationContext(servletContext.getContext());
        if (appContext == null) {
            // Spring behavior is always unbelievably surprising: under some
            // circumstances {@code appContext} may be null even though the app
            // context has been set via ApplicationContextAware: no idea WHY
            ApplicationContextWrapper wrapper = context
                    .getAttribute(ApplicationContextWrapper.class);
            appContext = wrapper == null ? null : wrapper.appContext;
        }
        return appContext;
    }
```

It works this way because it is doing a check and correcting it before proceeding (basically what the comment says). In the newest version the getApplicationContext is removed and the check no longer performed

```
    @Override
    protected Lookup createLookup(VaadinContext context,
            Map<Class<?>, Collection<Class<?>>> services) {
        WebApplicationContext appContext = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getWebApplicationContext(
                        ((VaadinServletContext) context).getContext());
        return new SpringLookup(appContext,
                (spi, impl) -> instantiate(appContext, spi, impl), services);
    }
```

I am not using spring boot just MVC and everything works fine with the older spring-vaadin version.  Is there a reason it no longer performs this check or something else that has been implemented that I can do to stop this from happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report - it seems that those changes (in PR [#740](https://github.com/vaadin/spring/pull/740)) have been overlooked for the latest versions of the Vaadin Spring add-on. We're going through the changes and making sure those get forward-ported and will be released soon for Vaadin 20 too.

For similar cases, when updating the Vaadin version breaks something, it is recommended to just directly open a new issue to the corresponding repository (like [vaadin/spring](https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues/new) or [vaadin/flow](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/new)) so it will be noticed immediately by the development team. Thanks

EDIT: The fix has been released in the [Vaadin Spring add-on version `17.0.1`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-spring/17.0.1). You can specify your project to explicitly use that version of `vaadin-spring` artifact. It will be included in Vaadin 20.0.2 release which is coming by next Monday 14th of June at latest.

Comment: For reference, the new cherry-pick: https://github.com/vaadin/spring/pull/833